# How can I specify padding depending on screen size

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, padding

I am developing an activity layout for Android (a simple form).
I want to specify the padding between different edit text in a linear layout depending on the screen size.

The more bigger is the screen I want to display the elements more separated (in order to avoid scrolling).

Is it clear? Thank you.

Comment: In your layouts for different screens, change the padding value. or check the answer below from Ahmad

Answer (score 3):

You can specify dimensions:

values folder:

```
<dimen name="padding">10dp</dimen>
```

values-sw400 folder:

```
<dimen name="padding">14dp</dimen>
```

And so on.

Now you just have to specify the padding like this:

```
android:padding="@dimen/padding"
```